# HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running unit tests and I keep running into the below exception:

> "OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: The HTTP request to the remote
>   WebDriver server for URL (*url*) timed out after 60 seconds".

I am facing this Exception, when another window opens. Second window opens, where data has to be entered in the text box, but execution fails.

I have checked many blogs, but no where found an apt solution to be implemented.

Code Updated:

```
IWebElement saveBtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphpopup_btnSave']"));
MouseClick(driver, saveBtn);

string currentHandle = driver.CurrentWindowHandle;
foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles)
{
    if (!handle.Equals(currentHandle))
    {
        driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    }
}

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

IWebElement authenticatePwd = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphpopup_txtPassword']"));
authenticatePwd.SendKeys("111");

IWebElement okBtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_cphpopup_btnUok']"));
MouseClick(driver, okBtn);

driver.Close();
driver.SwitchTo().Window(currentHandle);

MouseClick(driver, saveBtn);

IWebElement registerOkBtn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='btnOK']"));
MouseClick(driver, registerOkBtn);
```

Comment: Try downloading the latest chromedriver version from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.29/. Also update your browser and make sure you don't have old versions installed.

Comment: Unable to install now. Will try and update you...